# WebGL stop working after update to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: firefox, webgl

I have been developing something in webGl, and before the update I was able to run it on Firefox (Opera and Chrome fails, for some reason). After the update to latest Ubuntu version it has stopped working.

In the same computer I have Vista installed and webGl works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, so i guess that the Grapic card is ok.

I have tried changin the driver (is an nVidia), but stil fails.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I have the same issue! I'm running a nVidia GTX 560 TI and it refuses to load WebGL in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, WebGL does not work.  When I start Ubuntu 12.04 with a flash drive on my Netbook 1005HA this demo runs in FireFox: "http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson04/index.html".

After I actually installed 12.04 and ran the updates it no longer runs in FireFox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, happened after upgrading to 12.04. So, the question seems to be: How to install older VGA drivers?